# Magento sells products but fails to store the order

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have a silly problem - a `Magento 1.7.2.0` that works just fine, except for now and then it does not **store** the order in the database.

Emails go out, payment gets processed (owner gets confirmation from PayPal, for example) but no order is stored in the database. I did not rely on grid only, I checked the database - and nothing is there.

Also, last time this happened I checked increment values in eav_entity_store and thy were not updated - it says `130000030` and in the email order is `numbered 130000031` - so somewhere in the process it crashes.

First idea was to look in the error log but I was not able to see anything there that I could relate to this.

Now I need a fresh idea. Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: Is this issue associated with all payment type or just PayPal

Comment: Can't tell - sorry. The last occurrence was definitely PayPal. Since it's not my shop I don't have all the data - just what the owner seds me.

Comment: We need a whole lot more information. It sounds like PayPal is not returning the order correctly, but I have no idea what PayPal version you are using to know if that is a realistic idea or not.

Comment: Does the customer have an abandoned cart?

Comment: have you checked all the logs? Magento's system.log, exception.log, and also apache or zend php.log and error.log?

Comment: Are you using any 3rd party customizations that could affect the order processing? (custom checkout modifications?)  Try disabling 3rd party extensions and clearing your cache.

Comment: The problem is there's no way I can disable anything. The site is working worldwide so no disabling is possible at any time. We're using third-party plugin for multiple warehouses by Innoexts. This might be the source of issues, however I must prove it before I can expect any reaction from them.

Comment: @Peter Yes I checked the logs :)

Comment: @BenTruby I'll check that, thanks.